# Azure DevOps - can I specify the location for the automatically-generated pipeline?

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

When I push a new repository with an `azure-pipelines.yml` file in the base folder, a pipeline is automatically created. When I view the Pipelines page, I see that it is it is created at location `(root)\($projectname)\($projectname)`.

Can I configure the yml to create the pipeline in a different location, or do I have to do this manually?

Answer (score 0):

You may add any path here (under `review your pipeline YAML`):

[image]